# ElasticSearch - Match or less

Tags: elasticsearch

is there an way to query the following using elasticsearch (version 2) :

indexed documents examples :

```
{_id=1 , "tags":  [ "t1"]}
{_id=2 , "tags":  [ "t1", "t2" ]}
{_id=3 , "tags":  [ "t1", "t2", "t3" ]}
```

The following are query examples and expected results :

- **`"tags": ["t1"]`** ---> document `_ids=1`
- **`"tags": ["t1","t2"]`** ---> document `_ids=1,2`   (document #1 is expected too)
- **`"tags": ["t1","t2","t3"]`** ---> document `_ids=1,2,3`
- **`"tags": ["t2","t3"]`** ---> document `_ids=NONE`
- **`"tags": ["t1","t3"]`** ---> document `_ids=1` only

```
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{  "tags":  [ "t1"]}

PUT my-index-000001/_doc/2
{  "tags":  [ "t1", "t2" ]}

PUT my-index-000001/_doc/3
{  "tags":  [ "t1", "t2", "t3" ]}
```

The following query yield more than expected and include  document #3 too in addition to #1&#2

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tags": ["t1","t2"] 
    }
  }
}
```

And on the following, document #3 is not matched but either the expected #1

```
GET metric_*/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "tags": "t1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "tags": "t2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need a way exclude any document that has tag value that is not exist in the query tag list

thanks in advance

Comment: What is a search for `["t2","t3"]` supposed to yield? Nothing? And what about `["t1","t3"]`? Only document 1?

Comment: @Val yes , ["t2","t3"] yield none. ["t1","t3"] expected to return #1 only (question updated accordingly) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

taking the blacklist approach solve the issue (using must_not). since we know the full list of options in the tag field and it's relatively small.

query example :

```
GET tags/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "terms": {
                    "orgSourceIds": [
                        "t1",
                        "t2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```